# Как получить ID текущей страницы из URL?

Tags: php, dle, data-life-engine

Движок - DLE. Как получить ID текущей страницы?

Answer (score 0):

1. Установить 1 тип чпу.
2. В полной новости, сделать текущий код.

   $url = 'http://domen/category/podcateg/3-post4.html';

   $extract = array();
   preg_match('~\d+(?=-\w+.html)~', $url, $extract);

   echo $id = $extract[0];

Переменная ID содержит то, что вам нужно.